# get conversations of multiple contacts by using "content://mms-sms/conversations"

Tags: android, sms

I successfully get the all conversations in list, but there is a problem, if a conversation have more than one "recipient_ids", this code says invalid recipient_id
thanks in advance for help

```
public static void getAllMessagesInList(Context context) {

    Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://mms-sms/conversations?simple=true");
    String[] reqCols = new String[] { "_id", "recipient_ids", "message_count", "snippet", "date", "read" };
    Cursor cursor = context.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, reqCols, null, null, "date DESC");

    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            MessageBoxObject messageBoxObject = new MessageBoxObject();

            messageBoxObject.setRecipient_ids(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(reqCols[1])));
            messageBoxObject.setMessage_count(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(reqCols[2])));
            messageBoxObject.setSnippet(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(reqCols[3])));
            messageBoxObject.setDate(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(reqCols[4])));
            messageBoxObject.setRead(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(reqCols[5])));
            ConstantsValues.messageBoxObjects.add(messageBoxObject);
        }
    }
    cursor.close();

}
```

my MessageBoxObject class is this
public class MessageBoxObject {

```
String recipient_number;
String message_count;
String recipient_ids;
String snippet;
String readcount, snippet_cs, type, error, has_attachment, status;
Long date;
int read;

public int getRead() { return read; }

public void setRead(int read) { this.read = read; }

public Long getDate() { return date; }

public void setDate(Long date) { this.date = date; }

public String getRecipient_ids() { return recipient_ids; }

public void setRecipient_ids(String recipient_ids) { this.recipient_ids = recipient_ids; }

public String getMessage_count() { return message_count; }

public void setMessage_count(String message_count) { this.message_count = message_count; }

public String getRecipient_number() { return recipient_number; }

public void setRecipient_number(String recipient_number) { this.recipient_number = recipient_number; }

public String getSnippet() { return snippet; }

public void setSnippet(String snippet) { this.snippet = snippet; }
```

}

Comment: It seems `MessageBoxObject` is a custom class of yours, so in this case you should fix your code so that it works with multiple recipient ids.

Comment: it has getters and setters like
    String recipient_number;
    String message_count;
    String recipient_ids;
    String snippet;
    String readcount, snippet_cs, type, error, has_attachment, status;
    Long date;
    int read;

    public String getRecipient_ids() { return recipient_ids; }

    public void setRecipient_ids(String recipient_ids) { this.recipient_ids = recipient_ids; }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`recipient_ids` contains space separated contact ids.

So in order to get list of contacts you must tokenize `recipient_ids` than query `content://mms-sms/canonical-address` table for each id.

`cannonical-address` table has `_id` associated with contact `address`.

Than you can query by `ContactsContract.PhoneLookup` to get contact info.